# StudentDatabase using Linked List

Tags: java, list, linked-list

The problem is Implement a StudentDatabase class which implements OrderedList with a linked list. The student database contains each student’s name, student ID, and year. You should include a display class which prints the students in the database in order by Student Number. 
Here is my Student class:

And here is my add method:

Also here is my driver:

Comment: What is the value of `head` that is used in the `add` method you showed? I'm guessing it is null, then when you try and reference it by `current.setPrev(newItems);` you get a NPE

Comment: Which line gave you the NPE?

Comment: @alex Line 70, which is this one: current.setPrev(newItems); gave me the NPE.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't dealing correctly with the case of an empty list. In this case, `current = head` is already `null`, and when you try to look at the `next` field of the (`null`) node, you get an NPE. You need to check whether `head == null` and insert the new item at the front of the list if so.

Additionally, your `add` method is logically buggy; it always inserts an item at the end of the list. You need to be comparing as you go to insert the item in the correct spot.

Comment: Ok, so according to your answer I made all the changes in my add(), but somehow it's still give me error. And yeah, I'm trying to do one thing at a time and then print out to make sure I got them all right. So no order for it yet, just trying to get it to add, that's all.

Comment: @Drews Looks like you're making progress, but you have to be a lot more specific than "give me error". If the problem is just that you're not getting the printed output you want, you probably haven't implemented `toString()` in a helpful way. Look at [the implementation on `AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29) for ideas (or just extend `AbstractCollection`).

Comment: I just updated my code and I was able to print out the result. If you don't mind, can you help me with the order of the items. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Drews Think of a strategy and try it. If it doesn't work and you can't see why (a step-through debugger will be helpful), ask a followup question.

Answer (score 0):

Post your Log to know where you are getting NullPointerException,May be in while loop check instead current.getNext(),try current!=null like the below,

```
while(current!= null){
        current = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(newItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting a NPE is that the value of `head` to begin with is `null`. You need to change your code to have a check in there to see if this is the case.

Something like this:

```
// method declaration

LinearNode newItems = new LinearNode(head, items);
if (head == null) {
    head = newItems;
    return;
}

...
// the rest of the method
```

Comment: Let me try it again, because I have something similar to yours, but commented it out because it didn't work the first time around:          if (isEmpty())
   head = newItems;

Answer (score 0):

chrylis is right, it has to do with head possibly being null. You said the problem was in line 70 though, which involves `current.setPrev(newItems);` I think you need to implement both a check that head is null in `setPrev()` and `add()` like so:

```
if (head==null){
head=newItems;
return;
}
```

It's also a good idea to have `add()` return `true` because thats how java implements a few other `add()` methods in some of its other lists like `ArrayList<>`.